# Calculating weighted average using two different list of lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, average

I have 2 list of lists as follows:

`A = [[],[],[],[500,540],[510,560,550],[460,510,600,450]]`

`B = [[],[],[],[4000,2500],[3500,3600,3000],[3000,2900,3300,3500]]`

I would like to calculate the weighted average of values in every list of A using lists of B as corresponding weights. My output C should like like:

`C = [[],[],[],[515],[540],[505]]`

What I tried so far is using

```
C = []
for i in range(len(A)):
        avg = np.average(A[i], weights=B[i]) 
        C.append(avg)
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: `for i in A:` iterates over _elements_ of `A`, not indices. For example, the first `i` will be equal to the empty list `[]`, while the last `i == [460,510,600,450]`. Thus, `B[i]`, where `B` is a list, is an error because lists can't be indexed using other lists. Now you changed the code, so my comment doesn't make sense anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you need to deal with the empty lists. But no-one has given you the output you asked for. The other solutions also use counters (probably to mirror your own code), but this is not usually considered idiomatic Python.

I would probably do this in a list comprehension, and instead of indexing into both lists I'd take advantage of [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

You said you wanted rounded integers in in 1-item lists, like:

```
 C = [[int(np.round(np.average(a, weights=b), 0))] if a else [] for a, b in zip(A, B)]
```

This returns what you specified in your question:

```
[[], [], [], [515], [540], [505]]
```

But if it was me, I think I'd want the results as floats like:

```
C = [np.average(a, weights=b) if a else np.nan for a, b in zip(A, B)]
```

This results in:

```
[nan, nan, nan, 515.3846153846154, 539.7029702970297, 505.03937007874015]
```

which personally I would prefer.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have done works so far, except that it does not work for lists in A that have 0 len. So you can account for it through the following modification:

```
import numpy as np

A = [[],[],[],[500,540],[510,560,550],[460,510,600,450]]

B = [[],[],[],[4000,2500],[3500,3600,3000],[3000,2900,3300,3500]]

C = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    if len(A[i]) > 0:
        avg = np.average(A[i], weights=B[i]) 
        C.append(avg)
    else:
        C.append([])
```

Output:

```
C
Out[10]: [[], [], [], 515.3846153846154, 539.7029702970297, 505.03937007874015]
```

Answer (score 2):

The only issue is that `weights` can't be the empty list:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in average
  File "site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 524, in average
    raise ZeroDivisionError(
ZeroDivisionError: Weights sum to zero, can't be normalized
```

However, `B[:3] == [[], [], []]`, so you have three empty weights.

You can handle these empty lists accordingly:

```
C = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    avg = np.average(A[i], weights=B[i]) if B[i] else 0
    C.append(avg)
```

Output:

```
C == [0, 0, 0, 515.3846153846154, 539.7029702970297, 505.03937007874015]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my best solution:

```
import numpy as np

A = [[], [], [], [500, 540], [510, 560, 550], [460, 510, 600, 450]]

B = [[], [], [], [4000, 2500], [3500, 3600, 3000], [3000, 2900, 3300, 3500]]
C = list()

for list_values, list_weights in zip(A, B):
    if len(list_values) == 0 or len(list_weights) == 0:
        C.append([])
    else:
        weighted_average = np.average(list_values, weights=list_weights)
        C.append(weighted_average)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).